# How to pass event from one function to another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, listener, jquery-events

I need to pass somehow the information about pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on invoking the event by jQuery click function. I want invoke this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed.

```
$(selector).click();
```

This is simplified example:

https://jsfiddle.net/62mdur6o/

When you click on the first cell of table ("One") you do not get information about present <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in the event.

Is it possible to invoke click listener differently or to attach somehow this information to the event which will be passed to other listeners?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451726/multiple-item-selection-by-pressing-ctrl-button

Comment: That was is different, I want to invoke in javascript a listener with event  which has ctrl key pressed.

Comment: Thats for reference..You can achieve what you want from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger event using:

```
$('#cell').click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var e = jQuery.Event( event, {ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey} );
  $(this).next().trigger(e);
});
```

### -demo-

Answer (score 1):

Target each cells

```
    $('.cells').click(function (event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
           alert('ctrl pressed');
        } else {
            alert('just clicked');
        }
     });
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7grtr2a7/3/)